# Can't write in arabic using "arabtex"

Tags: arabic, arabtex

I am struggling to find a way to write in Arabic in Latex. Plz. note that my document is going to be in English. I just want to write arabic in some pages.

I am using `Ubuntu` system. I use `TexStudio` editor which uses `TeX Live 2017/Debian` and the editor's compiler is configured to be `pdflatex`.

I am trying to run the following short script I found [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Arabic):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{علوم الحاسوب}
    \section{تاريخ}
    \begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
        سلام 
    \end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

I am getting this error:

```
File `arabtoks.sty' not found. \UsePackage
```

Although I run the command to install the package in Live Tex:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
```

Any suggestions to solve the problem?

Comment: the missing sty is certainly not in texlive-xetex. Try `apt-cache search arabtex` to find the correct package (disclaimer, I don't have ubuntu and don't know if this really the right command to identify a package).

Comment: Thanks. I needed to run: `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-arabic` in addition to  `sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex`. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to run: `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-arabic` in addition to `sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex`. It works now.